# Creating then sending file as email attachment without saving on drive

Tags: python, email, email-attachments, smtplib

I wish I could send email attachment without saving it on drive, file should exist only for the time of script execution in temporary memory.

I have tried to use io.BytesIO() but it didn't work and I only got some errors.

```
import xlsxwriter
import smtplib
import os

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.utils import formatdate
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('sheet1')
worksheet.write(1, 1, 'Testing')
workbook.close()

SMTP_IP = 'some_ip'
smtpxd = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_IP)

content = 'here we go again'
msg_subject = 'TEST'
fro = 'foo@gmail.com'

toaddr = 'me@gmail.com'
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fro
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
msg['Subject'] = msg_subject

with open("test.xlsx", "rb") as attachment:
    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())

encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; 
filename="test.xlsx"')
body = ('%s\r\n' % content)
msg.attach(part)
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
text = msg.as_string()

rcpt = toaddr
rcpt = rcpt.split(', ')

smtpxd.sendmail(fro, rcpt, text)
os.remove('test.xlsx')
```

So this code sends an email with attachemnt and remove file after, but it doesn't really is what I wanted.

Comment: You need to show the code that fails to do what you do want, not the code that succeeds in doing what you don’t want.  Only the former can be debugged.